# How to inject dependency in custom class Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have Angular service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Services {
     public service1 = new Service1();
}
```

Where class `Service1` is:

```
export class Service1 {
    public http: HttpRequests;
    public repositoryModel: RepositoryModel;

    constructor() {
        this.repositoryModel = new RepositoryModel();
        this.http = new HttpRequests(this.repositoryModel);
    }
}
```

And class `HttpRequests` is:

```
export class HttpRequests {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private repository: RepositoryModel) {
}
```

Problem is HttpRequest depends on `private httpClient: HttpClient` so I need pass instance above in line:

```
this.http = new HttpRequests(<here>, this.repositoryModel);
```

How to do that?

I dont want to toss httpClient dependency from the top level beginning from `export class Services {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import HttpClientModule in your module in imports Array.

Then change your service to  :-

```
export class Service1 {
    public http: HttpRequests;
    public repositoryModel: RepositoryModel;

    constructor(private httpClient?: HttpClient) {
        this.repositoryModel = new RepositoryModel();
        this.http = new HttpRequests(this.httpClient, this.repositoryModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it good idea to inject dependency in top level and pass to low levels?

Comment: See first of all if you inject HttpClient in constructor or all, it will be using same instance due to dependency injection creating singleton instance. In above example i made httpClient as optional so service1 should automatically get instance of httpclient.

Comment: Yes, but my `class Service1 {}` it is custom class and it has no `@Injectable({})` only parent class where I initiate this class

Comment: that's not a problem even class without @injectable decoractor can inject other dependencies inside constructor. like we inject in component.

Comment: It does not work I get indefined `httpClient` on the line: `constructor(private httpClient?: HttpClient) {}` despite `HttpClientModule`

Comment: Parent class is: `
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Services {
    public Service1 = new Service1();}`

`class Service1 {
    public http: HttpRequests;
    public repositoryModel: RepositoryModel;

    constructor(private httpClient?: HttpClient) {
        this.repositoryModel = new RepositoryModel();
        this.http = new HttpRequests(this.httpClient, this.repositoryModel);
    }
}`

Comment: it will not work, if class using an angular feature, that should contains a dependency inject annotation or similar annotation. Example: Injectable, Directive or Component. This is exactly require for angular 10+. For less than 10, not good idea...